# Table auto-numbering using CSS

Tags: css

I need to add table numbers in my HTML document and prefer using CSS. I know we can add figure number etc, but I cannot find a way to add number to the table in this format "Table - 1" so that it appears before the table.

The following is my code but that puts the table number after the table head.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th scope="col">Cell 1 Head</th>
       <th scope="col">Cell 2 Head</th>
       <th scope="col">Cell 3 Head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Praesent ac risus malesuada</td>
        <td>sapien quis</td>
        <td>eget ipsum</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
    counter-reset:section 1;
 }

table:before{
    content:"Table - " counter(section);
    }
```

**Output:**

---

| Cell 1 Head | | Cell 2 Head | | Cell 2 Head |

---

Table - 1

---

..
..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the caption element `<caption></caption>` to your table, and then use this CSS:

```
body {
    counter-reset:section;
}
caption::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content:"Table - " counter(section);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x5d0fxwj/)**

Comment: thank you, It worked. Just what I wanted. But since the captions were appearing in the center, I modified caption properties as below ...        `    caption::before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content:"Table - " counter(section);
 float:left;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:100;
    }`